What do I do when I use gh-ost to change the length of a table field?
Here are the details of the error：
2024-05-30 19:06:04 INFO starting gh-ost 1.1.6
2024-05-30 19:06:04 INFO Migrating `quarantine`.`animal_declaration`
2024-05-30 19:06:04 INFO inspector connection validated on 10.221.55.162:9309
2024-05-30 19:06:04 INFO User has ALL privileges
2024-05-30 19:06:04 INFO binary logs validated on 10.221.55.162:9309
2024-05-30 19:06:04 INFO Inspector initiated on 10.221.55.162:9309, version 5.7.41-log
2024-05-30 19:06:04 INFO Table found. Engine=InnoDB
2024-05-30 19:06:04 INFO Estimated number of rows via EXPLAIN: 1847238
2024-05-30 19:06:04 INFO Recursively searching for replication master
2024-05-30 19:06:04 INFO Tearing down inspector
2024-05-30 19:06:04 FATAL Replication on 10.221.55.162:9309 is broken: Slave_IO_Running: No, Slave_SQL_Running: Yes. Please make sure replication runs before using gh-ost.
My architecture has two slave libraries, I tried to execute the show slave status\G from each library;
The result is Slave_IO_Running: Yes; Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
I don't know how to solve it!
